# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Netlover Broadband' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE VIEW Customer_view
as select customerID, first_name, last_name, DOB, contact_number, customer_address, Customer_email, joined_date,convert(int,c.Plan_Name) as 'mega plan'
from Customer as c, MegaPlan as m, ACCESS as a
where c.Plan_Name=m.Plan_Name and c.Plan_Name = a.AccessID
```

I'm trying to create a view which shows all details of all customers, mega plan and access type

How can I fix this

Comment: What do you need telling that the error doesn't already?

Comment: I'm trying to learn SQL on my own yes I know what the error is saying I just don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I think c.Plan_Name column datatype is varchar(n) and it contains some text value that why showing error. Don't convert it into integer.

Comment: Yes c.plan_name is a varchar. I have to convert into int otherwise I wont be able to view the view

Comment: you can use case statement 'case when value   LIKE '%[0-9]%' then cast(value as int)  end' but other than the numeric value it will return a null value.

Comment: @Nitika - you usually want a double negative - `value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`. Your like expression matches any string that contains *at least one digit*. There are many such strings that will not be convertible to an `int`. Mine does not match any string that contains any non-digit character. What's left by mine is empty strings and strings only consisting of digits.